# Spring Controller not found when running spring application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

i'm trying a sample spring project but the controller ive created is not evoking..please help.!

**controller.java**

```
package com.spring;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class loginController {
    @RequestMapping("/testing")
    public void add()
    {
        System.out.println("entered");

    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
          <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
          <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
  
</web-app>
```

**Login-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:ctx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd ">
    
    
    <ctx:annotation-config></ctx:annotation-config>
    <ctx:component-scan base-package="com.spring"></ctx:component-scan>

</beans>
```

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" isELIgnored="false"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Loading</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <a href="/testing"/>TakeMeToTheController</a>
</body>
</html>
```

the output entered is not printing on console which is written in controller class.

The jsp's are at src/main/webapp/

Comment: not working means can you elaborate

Comment: the controller is not calling when /testing url occurs

Comment: try running the application in debug mode

Comment: i mapped /testing to add method in controller class which should print "entered" on console but it is not doing that and giving me 404 with description as "The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists."

Comment: i dont know how to run in debug mode

Comment: try changing url pattern `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>`

Comment: no not working the welcome page also not coming now

Comment: Your controller tries to load a non-existing page. So what do you think the result of that is.

Comment: i didnt add any page in controller i just saying to print on console.

Answer (score 0):

config the location of Login-servlet.xml file in web.xml file as follows

web.xml

```
<web-app>
    <!-------- DispatcherServlet definition goes here----->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>file path of Login-servlet.xml file in your application/Login-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could change the url-pattern to "/**" .

Comment: What would changing the url-pattern to "/**" achieve?